# Drop table having name: <table_name>_(sysdate-1) only if the table exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to drop a table only if the table exist, can do it using plsql block

```
BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE <table_name>;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
            IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
                 RAISE;
            END IF;
END
```

But in my case the table name has sysdate (02062017) eg table001_02072017 and i need to delete all such tables with sysdate-1.
How can i do so?

Comment: Why do you need to drop a table only if it exists? What do you think will happen if you drop a table and it doesn't exist?

Comment: I need to drop table only if it exist.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. WHY do you need to drop it *only if it exists*? What bad thing do you think will happen if you drop a table that doesn't exist?

Comment: If i drop a table that doesnt exist it will give error. I am just avoiding that error handling.

Comment: That error does not need handling! All your processing can continue without any ill effects. That's what I keep trying to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the table with the given pattern from `user_tables` dictionary table and loop on the result to drop each one by one.

```
begin
  for t in (select table_name from user_tables
            where table_name like '%\_'||to_char(sysdate-1,'mmddyyyy') escape '\') 
  loop
    execute immediate 'drop table ' || t.table_name;
  end loop;
exception
  /* Handle your exceptions here. */
end;
/
```

Using `WHEN OTHERS` in your exception handling is discouraged. You should explicitly handle the errors.

Comment: `exception when others then...`? Please do not encourage poor practices!

Comment: @mathguy, well, you can do `exception when others then...` to display the error message in a more understandable format, then re-raise the error. i think there's an article on AskTom about that.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic sql will help you here just use

`execute immediate 'drop table ' || table_name;`

inside your procedure